# how to get LAMP offline installer?

Tags: installation, apache2, lamp

Where can I download the latest Apache, MySQL and PHP offline installers (maybe `.deb`)? (both `x64` and `x86`, if available)

I'm currently on Windows, and can't switch to Ubuntu and use `apt-get download` (or something like this).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this is direct link for LAMP/XAMPP

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/1.8.0/xampp-linux-1.8.0.tar.gz/download?use_mirror=ncu&download=

you can convert to deb with Alien. To install Alien type

```
sudo apt-get install alien
```

and for manual how to convert any format, type

```
man alien
```